# JQuery creating button but not clickable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have code that creates the body of a html-file.
I create it with JQuery.

The code is as followed:

SCRIPT JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   homePage();
});

function homePage(){
$.ajax({
    url: "http://events.restdesc.org/",
    type: "GET",
    dataType:'json',
    success: function (response) {
        var data = response;
        var html = $("<h1></h1>").text(data.title);
        var br = $("<br>");
        var eventbtn = $('<input />', {
            type  : 'button',
            id    : 'eventbutton',
            value : 'Events',
            on    : {
                click: getevents(data.events)
            }
        });
        html.append(br,eventbtn).appendTo($("body"));

    },

    error: function(error){
        console.log("the page was not loaded", error);
    },

});
}

function getevents(url){
    console.log(url);
}
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Index</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
</body>
</html>
```

The function homePage is directly called when you open the index.html.
It does work, I see a header and a button, however the code is automatically triggers, it prints the url in the console. But when I click on it, it doesn't print it in the console.
How do I need to change my code in order to get a button that only prints the given url when I click on the button?

Comment: please provide the full snippet and add html.

Comment: @FelixHäberle full snippet and html added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting data-url attribute and then access it using `$(this)`:

```
function homePage(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://events.restdesc.org/",
        type: "GET",
        dataType:'json',
        success: function (response) {
            var data = response;
            var html = $("<h1></h1>").text(data.title);
            var br = $("<br>");
            var eventbtn = $('<input />', {
                type  : 'button',
                id    : 'eventbutton',
                value : 'Events',
            });
            eventBtn.addClass('dynamic-btn');
            eventbtn.data('url', data.events);

            html.append(br,eventbtn).appendTo($("body"));
        },
        error: function(error){
            console.log("the page was not loaded", error);
        }
    });
}


$(document).on('click', '.dynamic-btn', 
    function (e) {
        console.log($(this).data('url'));
    });
```

Comment: This works but what if I have 50 buttons, and I don't know the id

Comment: So you can declare click `event` by class ;)

Comment: You're welcome ;) please mark my answer as useful if it helped

Answer (score 0):

Add click function to the button after it has already been appended to the body:

```
function homePage(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://events.restdesc.org/",
        type: "GET",
        dataType:'json',
        success: function (response) {
            var data = response;
            var html = $("<h1></h1>").text(data.title);
            var br = $("<br>");
            var eventbtn = $('<input />', {
                type  : 'button',
                id    : 'eventbutton',
                value : 'Events',
                on    : {
                    click: getevents(data.events)
                }
            });
            html.append(br,eventbtn).appendTo($("body"));

            eventbtn.click(getevents(data.events));
        },
        error: function(error){
            console.log("the page was not loaded", error);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
       homePage();
     });
    function homePage(){
    $.ajax({
    url: "http://events.restdesc.org/",
    type: "GET",
    dataType:'json',
    success: function (response) {
        var data = response;
        var html = "<h1>"+data.title+"</h1>";
        html += "<br>";
        html += '<input type="button" id="eventbutton" value="Events"/> ';
        $("body").append(html);
        $('input').click(function(){
            getevents(data.events);
        });                                    
    },

    error: function(error){
        console.log("the page was not loaded", error);
    },
   });
   }
   function getevents(url){
    console.log(url);
   }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```